# Can I add my own profile.php?

Tags: wp-admin, profiles, wp-editor

I really want load my own user-edit.php because I want add fields that can be updated using the WYSIWYG editor and edit profile like when I edit a page in WordPress. Is it a right way to accomplish that?

Thanks.

Comment: There are ways to add extra fields to the user edit/profile screens, you don't need to replace the file ( though no, the file can't be replaced )

Comment: And this is one of the many reasons wordpress is a joke. Look at that page, if you can't do better please just give us the ability to get rid of it please.